# C# setup project installs in C:

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

I have created a setup project for my `C#` project.

But when I install my program the installer writes all files in the **C: folder**.

The default location for my application folder is

> [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]

and I get the correct path when I start the installer.

Even if I select an other install path manually it installs the files in **C:**.

Comment: What type of "setup project" are you using here? There are several.

Comment: visual studio installer -> setup project

Comment: are you running as administrator?

Comment: @bones in which Visual Studio? the installer project types vary per IDE version. For example, 2012 includes InstallShield Limited Edition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138363/how-do-i-set-the-default-install-path-with-a-windows-installer

Comment: when I run the installer as administrator it works. Can I require admin rights for the setup filese?

Comment: May I recommend [this](http://www.installsimple.com/) for creating up to moderately complex setups. It has helped me greatly and it's free (not the pro).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer will default to the root of the largest drive (frequently C:)  whenever there is a problem with the Directory table.  Are you consuming any merge modules?  If so, you have to associate the MergeRedirectFolder with the TARGETDIR when you consume the module.  Otherwise your question is not answerable without examining a Windows Installer log.  You can obtain such a log by running:

```
msiexec /I foo.msi /l*v verbose_install.log
```